# How to fix corrupted IMEI number?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, imei

I have a Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9003 running `GINGERBREAD.XXKPE`. Right now when I type *#06# in the phone app, the popup shows:

[image]

(I recreated the image with my paint editor because I didn't want to use my camera. This is still an exact recreation of it.)

How would I put the IMEI back into memory? I have the IMEI from the back of the phone saying: `*5**07/0*/9****7/*`

I hid some numbers for obvious reasons. How would I put the IMEI back into the machine? Apparently, the IMEI is a 15 digit code but the IEMI on the rear of the phone is in this format: ABCDEF/GH/IJKLMN/O. Could you also rephrase this '15 digit code' to be 15 digits without slashes using letters A-O?

Comment: Are you sure this old device is still worth the effort? There are already countries and mobile network providers where it will not get a signal at all as 2G and 3G are already shut down.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this for a second phone and I can't sign in to google because the IEMI was lost.

Comment: I don't think the IMEI is the problem. The device is simply EOL, Google announced that those devices will no longer work: https://support.google.com/android/thread/118703101/sign-in-on-android-devices-running-android-2-3-7-or-lower-will-not-be-allowed-starting-september-27?hl=en

Comment: Ok, thanks, Robert! Is there a way to update the phone without a sim card? I tried SETTINGS>  ABOUT PHONE> SOFTWARE UPDATE> CHECK FOR UPDATE but it says I need a SIM card.

Comment: The SIM card is irrelevant, there are no updates your phone could receive. 2.3 is the highest version it can get by official updates.

Comment: try miracle box. i dont know much about it so don't revert to me.

Comment: Apparently, the IMEI is a 15 digit code but the IEMI on the rear of the phone is in this format: ABCDEF/GH/IJKLMN/O. Could you also rephrase this '15 digit code' to be 15 digits without slashes using letters A-O?

Comment: https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity#Structure_of_the_IMEI_and_IMEISV_(IMEI_software_version)